# Generate gradual transforming (n+1)D array morphing between start and end nD arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking for a numpy solution for generating a new (n+1)-dimensional array (3D "morph" in the example below) consisting of a number of n-dim intermediate arrays between an initial array and a final array (2D "start" and "end" in the example below).

I have tried the following:

```
import numpy as np

start = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)    
end = np.array([18, 10, 17, 15, 10, 2]).reshape(2, 3)
print(start)
print(end)
```

Giving us a start and an end array: in this case for start:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]]
```

and for end:

```
[[18 10 17]
 [15 10  2]]
```

The gradual transforming array can be generated as follows:

```
morph = np.zeros((4, start.shape[0], (start.shape[1]))) # adding 2 arrays in between

for i in np.arange(start.shape[0]):                     # for each row
    for j in np.arange(start.shape[1]):                 # for each column
        morph[:, i, j] = np.linspace(start[i, j], end[i, j], 4)
                                             # calculating array of intermediate values
print(morph)
```

and giving us the desired output:

```
[[[  0.   1.   2.]
  [  3.   4.   5.]]

 [[  6.   4.   7.]
  [  7.   6.   4.]]

 [[ 12.   7.  12.]
  [ 11.   8.   3.]]

 [[ 18.  10.  17.]
  [ 15.  10.   2.]]]
```

Is there a better (faster) way with a numpy routine doing this without the need of having 2 loops?  I was hoping for something like (generating a new linear spaced array between start and end):

```
morph = np.linspace(start.all(), end.all(), 4)
```

But then I get:

```
[ 0.          0.33333333  0.66666667  1.        ]
```

which is not the intention, nor the desired outcome.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `create_ranges_nd(start, end, 4).transpose(2,0,1)` from the linked Q&A.

Comment: @Divakar: Tried your function from your earlier answer: works great and I learned something about transposing as well!  Many thanks.